# Two rapid AJAX calls confuses PHP

Tags: php, ajax

I just ran into something weird. I have two JSON arrays which holds different data. Usually I just need data from one of them, but when I try to do a dual ajax call to get data from both arrays, I end up with the exact same data on both calls.

Say array 1 holds JSON data on users, and array 2 holds JSON data on houses, and I want to get data from both arrays: (PS! I cut out the `url` and `type` to save a couple of lines.)

```
$.ajax({
   async:false,
   data:"type=users&id=3,5,6",
   success: function(data) {
      data = JSON.parse(data);
      alert(data.length) //will alert 3 as expected
   }
});
```

Then I make the second call to get some houses in there as well:

```
$.ajax({
   async:false,
   data:"type=houses&id=2,4",
   success: function(data) {
      data = JSON.parse(data);
      alert(data.length) //alerts 3 as well...
   }
});
```

When I look at the params and response with Firebug, I can see that the params are correct, but the response is wrong.

In my PHP I even tried to just echo out whatever comes in doing this:

```
echo $_GET['id'] . ", " . $_GET['type'];
```

Which made the request look the exact same on both calls... If I put an alert inbetween the ajax calls, I get the expected result (since the system waits). But I thought putting them both to be synchronous would be enough to not crash up the calls..?

**edit:** I've tried creating a copy of the php file which is called within the AJAX function, and setting the calls to go to seperate files, which makes everything work as expected. So I'm fairly sure there's nothing wrong with the javascript.

**more edit:** If I remove the parameters from the second AJAX call, I still get the same result. Looking at the request with Firebug I can see that the params list is empty, but the response is still identical...

**even more edit:** Looking around in Firebug, I can see there is a header called `connection` which has the value of `keep-alive`, and then a header called `Keep-Alive` with the value of `300`. I'm guessing this might have something to do with it? Can't find anything on it in the jQuery docs, though...

**source code:** I've made a small test case, which reproduces the problem:

**PHP**

```
echo $_GET['test'];
die();
```

**HTML**

```
<sript>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $.ajax({
        type:"get",
        url:"bugtest.php",
        data="test=hello",
        success: function(data) {
          $("output").append(data);
        }
      });
      $.ajax({
        type:"get",
        url:"bugtest.php",
        data="test=world!",
        success: function(data) {
          $("output").append(" "+data);
        }
      });
    });
  </script>
  <h1>AJAX bug in Aptana's PHP server?</h1>
  <output></output>
```

That's all I have, and it does the same thing: Instead of getting `hello world!` like I'd expect, I get `hello hello`...

Comment: which version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: are the source code files available online for viewing?

Comment: Couple of issues in the current source, the php is printing the POST variable 'test', and the AJAX request is sending a GET variable 'test'. Additionally, the data in the call to ajax should be set with : not an =. What version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: The post/get was a typo. I'm using 1.3.2, but I've always set the data like an actual query string. And looking at firebug, it sends the data in correct format.

Comment: Try adding a call to, say, usleep(rand(50, 1000)) at the top of the PHP script.  Does making the script take longer to return results change the behavior you're seeing?

Comment: No, and this is interesting. I'd expect it to take longer to return each result, but I set `usleep` to 1million (1 second), and it only took 1 second to return both ajax calls, and not 1 second each, which means the PHP file was still "open"..?

Comment: just tested your code on Aptana .. output is hello world!

Comment: @Wbdvlpr: Really? Damnit! I've tried the code on both my Aptana's (running Linux and XP at work), and they produce the same error. Hmm...Time to test this on another computer then. Thanks for testing (:

Comment: I just tested it in Solaris in PHP Safe-Mode, got hello world! Had to make 3 edits, though, that are probably just typos but you probably want to fix for others testing: you put `sript` instead of `script` at the top, and both data parameters are using = instead of : (for the function, not the actual data, obviously). But yeah, fixed those, and hello world!

Comment: can you try making the first line of your php code `header("Connection: close");` and see if that helps?

Comment: @Stobor: thanks for the tip, but it doesn't help...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to determine wether PHP or JS is the problem you could use [Charles](http://www.charlesproxy.com/) to monitor your request (i trust charles more than firebug actually, dunno why) and generate a unique value serverside

```
<?php echo uniqid();
```

If both requests return the same value there is something wrong with your server, else it's the browser or jscode.

Comment: Yup, they are both identical... So I'm just gonna go ahead and accept that this is probably some error with Aptana's built in Jetty server...

Comment: Accepted as answer because it manages to point the fault somewhere, and because the bounty is out of time in a couple of hours, and someone should get the `150`

Comment: I've had a similar issue using Aptana, like the page is being cached, but it shouldn't be.  This gives me some more ideas to try, thanks for mentioning it!

Answer (score 6):

first of all, synchronous AJAX calls are fundamentally bad on a live system. Testing is ok, but don't do this at home, kids! Why? Because if the server doesn't answer in a second or at all (which is quite probable), the browser tab becomes non-responsive. In the worst case (old Mozillas) the whole browser will freeze.

`</teaching>`

- Caching should not be the problem, since the URLs are different, when you send GET requests (POSTs are most likely not cached at all).
- Your `alert()` test tells you, that it is not PHP's fault, because it sends back all stuff as requested
- So we remain with JavaScript:

  - If you would've hand-written the code, I'd guess, that you do a wrong check on the request's `onreadystate` (that is, the function to handle the requested data checks on the wrong request object)
  - Can you tell us, *which* library you use? Looks like prototype to me.

Cheers,

Comment: Yeah, this is for a prototype setup, so everything here is sorta hacked together :p I'm using jQuery, but I'm not so sure JS is to blame here. Firebug tells me that the params sent in are correct, but PHP are reading the old params for some reason...

Comment: just realized my comment might be confusing. It's a prototype setup as in I'm prototyping a new website, not using prototype framework. Sheez, what a bad name for a framework :p

Answer (score 5):

did you try adding timestamp to the URL ?? just to avoid caching etc

```
 data:"type=houses&id=2,4&"+timestamp
```

UPDATE:

or just try `cache:false` in Ajax

You using `async:false`

```
Async:
```

*By default, all requests are sent asynchronous (i.e. this is set to true by default). If you need synchronous requests, set this option to false. Note that synchronous requests may temporarily lock the browser, disabling any actions while the request is active.*

may be because of this temporary blocking .. you can try setting it to true.

Comment: Would I have to do something with that timestamp in PHP, then?

Comment: No, I know the urls params are different but just wanted to try. Did you try print_r($_REQUEST) ??

Comment: Yup. It will produce the same error. It will just continue to think I passed in users and 3 ids. `cache:false` didn't help either...

Comment: That will of course produce the same error, which kinda makes sense. It will have two calls over each other, so the params are likely to get messed up over the wire.

Comment: HTTP is sent over TCP, so messing up 'over the wire' just won't happen. If it's stuffing up, it'll be either on the client or server, and from the description, I'd presume JavaScript - PHP page executions don't have much room to influence one another.

Comment: It sounds like you've tried a lot of things, but if you're using GET still and assuming you copy/pasted the suggestion above, I would try this cache busting technique again but set the data as 'type=houses&id=2,4&_dc='+timestamp.  Note the addition of _dc= instead of trying to use the timestamp as its own request variable, since the timestamp will not be a valid variable (starts with a number) and therefore may not really be getting you safely by your cache.

Answer (score 2):

Try using POST.

Also if PHP receives 2 identical requests when they actually aren't supposed to be then it's not PHP's fault; the bug is somewhere between the place where you make the $.ajax call and where web-server passes the request to PHP.

Could you provide some more info about web-server? Which one do you use? Do you have some sort of catching or optimization going on there? Maybe you use some PHP framework or PHP "bootstrap" which could cache request?

You could also try to make a standalone test. Strip the Ajax code out and use minimal php script which just echoes the request. See if you get the same bug.

Some copy-paste data of requests sent and requests received in php would be nice.

---

I've never seen anything like this, I'm almost sure it's catching related. As a workaround you could just merge both requests in one, you would have to change the PHP script a bit. It's actually probably a better solution as well since you should always try to make as few requests to the server as you can.

Comment: POST gives the same result. I'm just using Aptana's built in server, and I have no idea what the settings are for it...

Comment: And taking the time (5 seconds) to upload and test this on our server at work, I found that it actually works... :\ So that would mean that something's up with Aptana's PHP server set-up...

Comment: I think the server just couldn't handle it, or it's a bug. Maybe open an issue over at Aptana bug-tracker and see what they have to say about it. That is if you can make a small test case which reproduces the bug.

Comment: I've checked the provided test case (it contains errors, btw) on Apache 2.2.12 and PHP 5.3.0, with different versions of jQuery - all return the correct answer (although jQuery eats up the space between Hello and world!, but that's beside the point ;) - so my guess is that this is an issue on the server (Aptana) side.

Comment: Yeah, I've also tested on Apache recently, and that works... So I'm now fairly sure this problem is isolated to the Aptana set-up somehow. And I also noticed the space being eaten up, but as you said: beside the point. Which errors were there, btw?

Comment: Not much space, so: my HTML test file: http://pastie.org/642489, my PHP test file: http://pastie.org/642490

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the second request in a timeout which waits for 0 seconds.

```
$.ajax({
   async:false,
   data:"type=users&id=3,5,6",
   success: function(data) {
      data = JSON.parse(data);
      alert(data.length) //will alert 3 as expected
   }
});

setTimeout(function(){$.ajax({
   async:false,
   data:"type=houses&id=2,4",
   success: function(data) {
      data = JSON.parse(data);
      alert(data.length) //alerts 3 as well...
   }
})}, 0);
```

Comment: Already tried that, and it doesn't help. I have to set the timeout to at least 500ms for it to work...

Comment: That doesn't set a timeout correctly. That's passing the *result* of calling $.ajax() to be called after 0ms. Hell, if you do this and there's a difference changing between setting 0 and 500, things smell worse than fishy Mr peirix.

Comment: Yeah, and that's why I think there's something wrong with the PHP, and not javascript...

Comment: Thanks Mead, I fixed that now. Not sure if peirix tested it the proper way, or the way I originally did it

Comment: I actually misread your answer, and thought you had this all along. So this is what I've tried, and it works if I set the timer to something along the lines of 500ms or sometimes even higher.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible, that there is some Problem with the data variable ?

What happends if you change your second request to:

```
$.ajax({
   async:false,
   data:"type=houses&id=2,4",
   success: function(dataHouse) {
      data = JSON.parse(dataHouse);
      alert(dataHouse.length)
   }
});
```

Comment: Nope, because looking at the response from the php file, I can see that the response is wrong. So I think the error must be in PHP somehow...

Comment: But are you sure that the same request data isn't being sent twice? I'm wondering what ArneRie is, if that "data" variable is getting tripped up inside the ajax method somehow. Have you tried this in Firebug and checked what parameters are actually going out?

Comment: @Erryn: Yeah, as noted in my question, I've verified that the parameters are correct, but the request is messed up somehow.

Answer (score 0):

Put the next ajax call in the response of the first ajax call:

```
function nextAjaxCall(){
  $.ajax({
    async:false,
    data:"type=houses&id=2,4",
    success: function(data) {
      data = JSON.parse(data);
      alert(data.length) //alerts 3 as well...
    }
  });
}
$.ajax({
  async:false,
  data:"type=users&id=3,5,6",
  success: function(data) {
    data = JSON.parse(data);
    alert(data.length) //will alert 3 as expected
    nextAjaxCall();
  }
  error: function(){
    //error handling
    nextAjaxCall();
  }
});
```

Make sure that you call the second ajax even if the first one doesn't return successfully.

Comment: Still get the same result. As I mentioned in your other answer, PHP seems to need at least 500ms before it can accept any new AJAX calls...

Answer (score 0):

Try setting global:false in the jQuery ajax() options.

If that doesn't help, try calling two different PHP pages - one for houses and one for users. If that works, it should at least help narrow the problem down.

Comment: As noted in one of my edits, I've tried with two different files, and that works...Setting `global:false` doesn't help either... :\