# receive ajax response in two steps

Tags: php, ajax

In my project, after user input, an AJAX call is sent to the server, but the process might take some seconds to finish and it's boring for users to wait for.

So I want to give response in two steps. first step will give back the more important data, and then the rest of process is done and finally the rest of data should be given back.

first I tried to make two ajax calls , but it makes some additional problems which makes it a bad idea.

Is this possible to give ajax response and update the page in two steps, or Is there some other type of technology to handle this job?

Thanks for your help

Comment: What "additional problem" does two ajax calls make?

Comment: You can, just remember to put the other call in success() or done(), or you could use delegation.

Comment: the *two jobs* are related and can't be done in parallel. another way is to call the second ajax call after the first is finished, but this way is not safe and could be controled by the user(or might be prevented by the user)

Comment: If you don't want to wait than don't use `async` approach.

Comment: @jhonraymos : I didn't tell I don't want to wait. the response should be appeared soon. but I just want to give the first part of response sooner(in 2 seconds) and then the latter(for example in 8 seconds)

Comment: @Almir Sarajčić : what is delegation? would you please explain more?

Comment: @ali it depends on your server...for more speed use `websockets`..

Comment: WebSockets *are* better, but you can also use chunked encoding to send the data, and use `onprogress` to get the data as it comes.

Comment: @Shaquin Trifonoff : 'onprogress' is a property of jquery $.ajax method?

Comment: @ali `onprogress` is an event from an XMLHttpRequest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the callback function of the first ajax request you start the second one.

Don't start two in parallel, because only one gets executed at a time (in case you use sessions server side) and which one is first is more or less random.

Comment: read my comment at bottom of the question. In this way the second ajax call is not safe. It could be controlled by the user. and it's possible that this second call never occur...

Comment: yeah, sure, but doesn't stop you from doing it.

Comment: Why vote down?
This is good answer (not saying only because I typed something similar in comments on question :D).

Answer (score 0):

As [Niko Sams](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13153028/920303) explained, you can put second AJAX call inside success callback of first one.

**Other solutions**

Take a look at this:
[Two rapid AJAX calls confuses PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1491228/two-rapid-ajax-calls-confuses-php)
Maybe this can solve your problem with two AJAX calls.

http://api.jquery.com/delegate/
or you can trigger event with .trigger() after one AJAX call succeeds with and add event listener with .on() method.